# Angular 4 - maximum call stack core.js

Tags: angular, typescript

We are developing some application, we found out very nasty call stack error.
Application work well but after sometime there is this exception.

I includes my app module code, we declared global service injector and maybe there is problem. Also i found information that wrong routes can cause this kind of error but i want to wait for any answer before posting them.

Here is example of use this injector in some constructor

```
 this.translateService = ServiceLocator.injector.get(TranslateService);
```

call stack

```
defaultErrorLogger @ core.js:1671ERROR RangeError: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[LocationStrategy -> PlatformLocation]:
 StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[LocationStrategy -> PlatformLocation]:
   Maximum call stack size exceeded
   at resolveToken (core.js:1294)
   at tryResolveToken (core.js:1242)
   at StaticInjector.push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.StaticInjector.get (core.js:1139)
   at resolveToken (core.js:1298)
   at tryResolveToken (core.js:1242)
```

App module

```
  @NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    AppRoutingModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    BrowserModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    CoreModule,
    ServiceWorkerModule.register('/ngsw-worker.js', { enabled: environment.production }),
  ],
  providers: [
    AppConfigService,
    { provide: APP_INITIALIZER, useFactory: loadConfigService , deps: [AppConfigService], multi: true },
    httpInterceptorProviders,
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppModule {
  constructor(private injector: Injector) {    // Create global Service Injector.
    ServiceLocator.injector = this.injector;
} 
}

export function loadConfigService(configService: AppConfigService): Function {
  return () => { 
    return configService.load(); 
  };
}
```

Comment: A callstack exceeded error usually means you are calling a function that calls itself. The error doesn't say where or what is in error, you'll have to find it yourself.

Comment: no way sherlock :D I know that, but message have some info so i want to ask :)

Comment: You stated that you think it comes from either routing or injectors. I'm telling you it doesn't, your code is in error. Try finding recursive calls, to simplify it I would personally reset my commits until I find a version of my project that works, then check in the commit diff what is making recursive calls.

Comment: use chrome debugger to narrow down the code and find something which is recursive (ex: inside observable subscribe, calling the same function again).

Comment: Seems an issue with routes. Could you please share your routing code?

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/QljsgNKImSofHWnlVlex?p=info  there is three files, one is file that contain lazy routes, one mobile routes which contain mobile-router and one example router of mobile child route. For me there is problem with multiple mobile path